# Button Icon color is not changing using the fill CSS

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, css, slds, svg-icon

Trying to change the icon color to red, Icon color is not changing. when i use `fill` It just filling the color in middle as below.

[image]

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_icon" title="Add New" onclick={handleAddNewObject} style=fill:red>                                                                           
<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon_container_circle slds-icon-action-new">
<svg class="slds-icon lds-button__icon  slds-icon_x-small"
aria-hidden="true">
<use style=fill:red xlink:href="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/action-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#new"></use>
</svg>
</span>
</button>
```

Note: The Color will be dynamic for each user, It has been configured in custom Object.s

Is there any way we can change the action icon color?

Comment: The fill you'rve implemented is the fill of the svg.  In this case, the svg is the plus symbol, so it's working exactly as you've implemented it.  Have you tried adding some css to the span that includes the `slds-icon_container_circle`?  That sounds like a better place to change the colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nick cook said, You are filling the color in svg.

Remove the `style=fill:red` from svg and add `background: red` in span as below

```
<button class="slds-button slds-button_icon" title="Add New" onclick={handleAddNewObject}>                                                                           
<span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon_container_circle slds-icon-action-new" style=background: red>
<svg class="slds-icon lds-button__icon  slds-icon_x-small"
aria-hidden="true">
<use xlink:href="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/action-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#new"></use>
</svg>
</span>
</button>
```